# (JavaFX) How do I initialize my TreeView?

Tags: java, javafx, treeview, scenebuilder

Im not able to initialize my treeview,my fx:id is right but the output just gives me a blank treeview.

I am using scene builder with fxml controllers.

This is my Fxml Controller.

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
import java.net.URL;
import static java.time.Clock.system;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeView;

/**
 *
 * @author Man Eesh
 */
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private TreeView<String> treeView;
    @FXML
    private Label label;

    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event){     

    }  
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // System.out.print("here");
        label.setText("Hello World!");
        TreeItem<String> root = new TreeItem<>("Root Node");
        root.setExpanded(true);
        System.out.print("here");
        root.getChildren().addAll(
            new TreeItem<>("Item 1"),
            new TreeItem<>("Item 2"),
            new TreeItem<>("Item 3")
        );

        treeView.setRoot(root);


    }    

}
```

Comment: Your controller works just fine for me, with the simplest compatible FXML file and application class that I could write. Can you [edit] your question to include a minimal FXML file and application class that demonstrate the problem?